# Unable to load an applet in HTML using Firefox

Tags: java, applet

Applet Code:

```
package p9;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.TextArea;
import java.awt.TextField;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import org.alicebot.ab.*;
import org.alicebot.ab.utils.IOUtils;

public class CHAT extends Applet implements ActionListener
{
    public static TextField tf;
    public static TextArea ta;
    public static Bot bot;
    public static Chat chatSession;
    public static String r;
    public static String textLine;   
    public void init()
    {
        r="C:\\Users\\ASUS\\Desktop\\program-ab-0.0.4.3 (1)";
        bot = new Bot("super", r);
        chatSession = new Chat(bot);

        Color c=Color.ORANGE;
        setBackground(c);
        tf=new TextField(200);
        ta=new TextArea(50,250);
        ta.setEditable(false);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        add(ta);
        add(tf);

        tf.addActionListener(this);
        //setSize(400,400);
        setVisible(true);  
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) 
    {
        try 
        {
            textLine = "";

            textLine = tf.getText();
            if ((textLine == ""))
                textLine = MagicStrings.null_input;
            else 
            {
                ta.append("YOU->  "+textLine+"\n\n");
                String request = textLine;

                String response = chatSession.multisentenceRespond(request);
                ta.append("ROBOT->  " + response+"\n\n");

                tf.setText("");
                if(request.toLowerCase().equals("bye"))
                    System.exit(0);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

HTML code:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
     <applet code="p9.CHAT" archive="APPLET.jar" height="400" width="400"></applet>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am using Netbeans IDE 8.2. When I try to run above code it displays only a blank screen in Firefox. APPLET is a java class library, I have added it to my web application.
When I run the Applet program it is working properly with AppletViewer however when I try to load the applet in html it is not loading.
I have used JSP plugin and Applet tag.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/moving-to-a-plugin-free-web). 3) **Be sure the [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) is configured to show.  If there is no output at the default level, raise the level and try it again.** I expect there'll be some juicy stack traces from the bot trying to reach a ..

Comment: .. file location on the user's machine which does not exist, or which will be blocked by security on yours.

Comment: A warning about applets in browsers to be a dying if not dead technique, as Andrew Thompson hinted at with his links.